# Proof that cardinality of inverse image will always be the same for a particular group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $(G, \star)$ and $(H, \blacksquare)$ be groups, and let $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism. Let's also assume $\varphi$ is surjective. For any $h\in H$, we define $\varphi ^{-1}(h) = \{g\in G|\varphi (g)=h\}$.

How can I prove that for $h_1,h_2\in H$, $|\varphi ^{-1}(h_1)|=|\varphi ^{-1}(h_2)|$ ? That is, the number of elements of $G$ that $\varphi$ maps to $h_1$ is the same as to $h2$.

Comment: Well, that isn’t exactly true. What happens if $\varphi$ isn’t surjective?

Comment: @Gauss Good point. I will edit the question. Let's assume $\varphi$ is onto.

Comment: In that case, have you seen the first isomorphism theorem (sometimes called the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms)? It gives you an explicit description of what $\varphi^{-1}(h)$ “looks like”

Comment: @Gauss I was not familiar with that, no. I am having trouble interpreting the literature on it. I am new to group theory, so I'm wondering if there's a simple way I could prove the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) Define $Ker_{\phi} =\{g\in G | \phi(g)= e_H \}$ this is the "kernel" of the map $\phi$

Step 2) For $h \in H$ since $\phi$ is surjective there exists $g_h \in G$ such that $\phi(g_h)=h$, now let $w \in G$ be "another" element in $G$ such that $\phi(w)=h$ we then have:

$$\phi((g_h)^{-1}w)=\phi(g_h^{-1})\phi(w)=\phi(g_h)^{-1}h=h^{-1} h = e_H$$

hence $(g_h)^{-1}w \in Ker_{\phi}$

Step 3) if $u,v \in G$ are such that $u^{-1} v \in Ker_{\phi}$ then $\phi(u)=\phi(u)e_H=\phi(u)\phi(u^{-1}v)=\phi(u(u^{-1}v))=\phi(v)$.

Step 4) let $h_1, h_2 \in H$ be given, there exists $g_1, g_2$ such that $\phi(g_1)=h_1, \phi(g_2)=h_2$ now define the function $F: \phi^{-1}(h_1) \rightarrow \phi^{-1}(h_2)$ as follows:

$$F(g)=(g_2)(g_1^{-1})g$$

with what was said above you can clearly see that $F$ is injective and surgective aswel, hence we must have:
$$|\phi^{-1}(h_1)|=|\phi^{-1}(h_2)|$$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.